# How to keep my WPF C# app running when user cancel the shutdown

Tags: c#, wpf, application-shutdown

I have a C# WPF app which will run as a background process. The purpose of the app is to calculate the break taken by the user. We use lock and consecutive unlock as break. If the break exceeds certain minutes through an UI I will get the reason for the break. The requirement is , it has to keep on running in the background. But it fails in the below scenario:

User clicks shut down but due to some unsaved changes in other apps , say notepad etc., the shutdown is stopped and user cancel the shutdown. Now my app is no longer running.

Below steps I tried but no luck:

1)On `SystemEvents_SessionEnding` I tried to run a .bat file which will start my app after 5 minutes delay.

2. Tried the same above logic in a powershell script.

Both are failures. Please help me here.

My Code:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{

    SystemEvents.SessionEnding += SystemEvents_SessionEnding;
    Application.Current.Exit += Application_Exit;
    //and some mutex codes are here
}

private void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Reason == SessionEndReasons.Logoff || e.Reason == SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown)
        {
            if(SharedResource.Instance.IsSystemLocked ==false)
            {
                App_InsertLockDetais(false, null, null);  //Here I do some sqllite local database insert
            }                    
        }

        if(e.Reason == SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown)
        {
            ReInitiateApp();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHandler.HandleException(ex, "SystemEvents_SessionEnding");
    }
}

private void ReInitiateApp()
{
    try
    {
        string appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        string batFilePath = Path.Combine(appPath, "phoenix.bat");

        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = batFilePath,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        process.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHandler.HandleException(ex, "ReInitiateApp");
    }
}

private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
{
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch -= SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
    SystemEvents.SessionEnding -= SystemEvents_SessionEnding;
    _mutexuser?.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

My phoenix.bat file

```
@echo off
timeout /t 600 /nobreak
start "" "C:\ProgramData\MyExeFolder\MyExe.exe"
```

Comment: So your question is why does your application shutdown after the user cancel the shutdown process? In this case maybe insert your code, so other can pinpoint your mistake.

Comment: What is the purpose of this functionality ?

Comment: Do you want to perform some tasks before shutdown is fired? Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @bazsisz I shared my code.

Comment: @CodeJunkie I will track user activity. So even if user kill this app using another watchdog app it will bring it up again. So it will be always running in background, but user cancelling the shutdown is my current loop hole.

Comment: @Ihdina . Mine is a background process. My problem is , if the shutdown is smooth no issues(from my app there is no need to get confirmation from the user.), but if user cancels it , I need a event handler to restart my app.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably split your application in two parts

The part that does all the actual work should run as a service. This makes it run independently of the user session, and immune to things like "cancel shutdown". The service can also be configured to restart the service on failure, or the entire computer if needed.

You can then have a separate UI application to interface and control the service. This application only needs to run when the user actually wants to do something, and can be freely closed without affecting the background work. The user just needs to restart it if it is closed for any reason, just like all other applications.

Use your favorite type of inter process communication protocol to make these two components talk to each other.

This pattern is common for server oriented software, like databases. The actual database runs as a service, with an administration tool that is run as a regular application.

Trying to keep an UI application running after the user or OS has explicitly told it to close can easily become user hostile.

Comment: I have several constrains in the deployed environment. I am restricted with one exe and another watchdog exe. I am not allowed to create service or any more exes. Also the app will run on user account and user won't be local admin.

Comment: If you are not local admin you are probably not allowed to run "always on" applications.

Comment: I tried to run the app in admin mode initially , but I could not get the current logged in user name. So I designed to run it in user account and also the app is already in production.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a background process in a WPF project. Create a service
and a GUI to start and stop the process where both project are independent of each other. You can create a windows setup project to install both your service and WFP app for easy installation.
I have provided the sample Project Structure with some elaboration.

[image: Service App Project Structure]

Comment: App is already in production environment and I have several constrains in the deployed environment. I am restricted with one exe and another watchdog exe. I am not allowed to create service. Also the app will run on user account and user won't be local admin.

Comment: @Alphonse ok Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to get hate for this, but your use context sounds awfully suspicious. You have no admin rights, the app runs in the background and it cannot be shutdown by the user. That seems pretty hostile towards the user and could easily be used for malicious purposes (keyloggers etc...)

Comment: We use the app in our own production environments and we are the admin for all the systems. But running the app in the admin mode, I was unable to get the current logged in user. So I decided to run it in the user account level.